# Adding some python flavor to C++

Tags: c++, python

## Curly braces

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    line one
    line two
}
if (something)
{
    line three
    line four
}
else if(something)
{
    line five
    line six
    line seven
}
else
{
    line eight
    line nine
    line ten
}
```

I am a lazy typist and in recent years I've developed a dislike for curly braces in C++. Not that I think they are unnecessary; actually I can't live without them in long pieces of code. But when a branch of code contains only 3 to 5 lines, the increased indentation alone seems perfectly sufficient in making the context clear, and the curly braces don't seem to do much more than taking up my precious screen space (especially when I use vertical splits) and requiring me to press more keys, which, owing to their not-so-convenient positions on my keyboard, also add more strain to my fingers.

So, I'm thinking of doing a preprocessor to allow me to use some python-flavored c++, like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    line one
    line two

if (something)
    line three
    line four
else if(something)
    line five
    line six
    line seven
else
    line eight
    line nine
    line ten
```

So we make the curly braces optional in short branches of code, and by doing this the code becomes cleaner.
If I have a lot of functions that consist of no more than 8 lines, getting rid of the curly braces really make a huge difference to me. Things seem more compact, clean; and being able to see more useful code in one screen somehow just makes me feel better. People who do the kind of thing below will probably be thankful as well:

```
void blahbalh(){
    code...
}
```

Apparently people started doing this decades ago for the sake of screen space. Now, wouldn't it be better if the curly braces simply become optional? That is, we use them only when the code contained becomes relatively long.

## Symbols in general

To add more python flavor to C++. I actually think that the braces surrounding the conditions can also be done away with. It looks *really* different from C++, but after I got used to python I actually found it to be quite elegant:

```
if something:
    line three
    line four
elif something:
    line five
    line six
    line seven
else:
    line eight
    line nine
    line ten
```

Generally, I've found that python tends to use far fewer symbols, which is a good thing:

- Symbols cause more finger strains than plain text, because of their relatively inconvenient positions on our keyboards and because of the need to press SHIFT (qwerty and Dvorak are the same here)
- Since the alphanumerical keys are easier to press, we can type faster if we avoid using symbols. And my experience with this is that I feel a more natural *flow* when I don't have to frequently press the shift key.

So we could have more plain-text operators, like using `and` in place of `&&`, and `or` in place of `||`, etc. And we can have python-styled for loops, which are really easier to type

What do you guys think of this python-flavored c++? Any suggestions?

I'm thinking of doing it all as a preprocessor that basically does some simple source-to-source transformation. This looks like the easiest way to go without having to define a new language.

Comment: I love c++ and I love python. I don't love this idea.

Comment: Lazy to type few curly brace, but going to implement a custom flavor of compiler?

Comment: Really, don't try to turn C++ into something it is not. Such a thing may lead only to a lot of headaches.

Comment: Do NOT try to reshape the language. This will confuse the community and if your code is worth reusing it will end up being rewritten by someone else after digging into your *syntax*. Use IDEs with auto correct, auto indent, etc. Write IDE plugins if really worth it. BUT DO NOT RESHAPE THE CPP FILES YOU DISTRIBUTE.

Comment: LOL I knew this question would get closed. Should try to get help somewhere else :(

Comment: @meh I'm not quite familiar with this place. Is it true that StackOverflow is Q&A site that does not accommodate opinions? Any pointers?

Comment: *Is it true that StackOverflow is Q&A site* Wow. I mean, just... wow.

Comment: @ta.speot.is I don't know. I had the impression that it used to be something different from the way it is today. Maybe I never paid enough attention to get it right.

Answer (score 5):

> I am a lazy typist and in recent years I've developed a dislike for curly braces in C++ ... and the curly braces don't seem to do much more than taking up my precious screen space

Write your code like this, and switch to an IDE that types the braces for you. You can continue to write code that the rest of us will understand.

```
for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    line one
    line two
}

if (something) {
    line three
    line four
} else if (something) {
    line five
    line six
    line seven
} else {
    line eight
    line nine
    line ten
}
```